# How to disable button of check box in Android 4.0

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm using

```
 android:button="@null"
```

for disabling button in check box, its working fine in in 4.2 and upper, but its not working in 4.0 (Ice cream sandwich).

How it looks in 4.0 (Ice cream sandwich)

[image]

How it looks in upper versions.

[image]

My xml class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<com.search.Monthcheckbox
    android:id="@+id/ch1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="OCT"
    android:textColor="@color/tripoto_grey"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
```

Help me out.

Comment: is it a *checkbox*?? Show your xml

Comment: Yes, its a custom checkbox.

Comment: then you need to check attributes of *Monthcheckbox*

Comment: can u be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom drawable and set it as `android:button="@drawable/selector"`

`selector.xml` in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
              <item android:state_checked="true" 
                  android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" /> <!-- checked --> 
              <item android:state_checked="false" 
                 android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" /> <!-- unchecked-->
              </selector>
```